# Why the author claims this function call not to be a recursive call?

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

The author claims that the next call is not a recursive call, but I don't get why.

[image: Taken from a Caltech course slides]

Source: http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/haskell/lectures/haskell_lecture_5.pdf

Comment: I think the emphasis should be read on "function". It's sure enough recursion, only, `gcdST` is not a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code *is* recursive (it is defined in terms of itself). I believe that @leftroundabout's idea about the emphasis being on *function* is accurate. The next slide says that

```
do putY (y - x)
   gcdST
```

is

```
Recursive data definition
* not recursive function call
* like ones = 1 : ones
```

I.e. there is no recursive *function call* because `gdcST` is not a function (it takes no argument!). This is a recursive data definition.

Comment: "Recursive data definition" that is new to me. But being strict, it is a function, isn't it? I mean, it's declared as a function and performs computation each time is called.

Comment: @LayGonzález No, it's not a function - it takes no argument. In Haskell, values are only function if they have a `->` in their type. And, just like the slide says, there is no "calling" - since there is no function. It only performs computation in the same sense that the second occurrance of `ones` in `ones = 1 : ones` performs a computation yielding a list. It does evaluate to a value, that's right.